# Appending data to your table on success - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am able to successfully query my database to find an existing data. But now, i don't know how to make the table only display the item being search for. When the textbox is cleared, the table should go back to it default state.

How do i achieve this please?

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
         {
            $query = "%".$request->get('myInput')."%";
            $students = Student::where('name','LIKE',$query)->where('grade_id',Auth::user()->grade_id)->paginate(5);             
             return view('customer.index',compact('stduent','query'));

         }
```

**JS**

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
                var doneTypingInterval = 100;  //time in ms (5 seconds)

                $("#myInput").on('keyup', function () {


   clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                if ($('#myInput').val()) {
                    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
                }
            });
        });

        //user is "finished typing," do something
        function doneTyping() {
            var key = $('#myInput').val();

            if (key.length >= 1) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/admin/search/?myInput='+key,
                    type: 'GET',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#table").slideUp('fast');

                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#table").append(data);
                        $("#table").slideDown('fast');
                    }
                });

       }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
success: function (data) {

   var table = $("#table tbody");

   $.each(data, function(idx, elem){

   table.append("
   <tr><td>"+elem.id+"</td>
   <td>"+elem.name+"</td>   
   <td>"+elem.lastname+"</td>
   </tr>
   ");
   });
  }
```

since you are checking `if (key.length >= 1)` that means if user does not input anything then leave the table with the current content. [Read this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: please check your syntax well. it looks buggy to me

Comment: what looks buggy? be more precise ?

Comment: where the rows are being appended to the table, when i comment that side out of my code,  it runs.. it says invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

You may use `$("#table").empty()` to clear in it before appending data for new search

Comment: nothing is actually being appended to my table when there is success. but in my console i see an array of object being found like ` {id: 1, name: "jones", phone: "23242349243", address: "pickson" …}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: The data is a json data you cant directly append it to table. You should use attr of it to append, like `table.append("<tr><td>"+data.name+"</td><tr>")`. and before that you could apply `$("#table").empty()` to clear table for new search result

Comment: I don't get how your you empty the table.. this is what i want, when the user starts typing, it has to filter